# (C++) Getter and setter in a class not working as intended

Tags: c++, class, oop, getter-setter

I am trying to write a simple code where the getter and setter is used.

Here is the test_class.hpp file

```
#ifndef TEST_CLASS_HPP
#define TEST_CLASS_HPP

class test_class
{
private:
    int num;
public:
    test_class(int num);
    ~test_class();
    int& get_num();
    void set_num(int& num);
};


#endif
```

Here is the test_class.cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include"test_class.hpp"

test_class::test_class(int num):num(num){};
test_class::~test_class(){};

int& test_class::get_num(){return num;}
void test_class::set_num(int& num){num = num;}
```

And here is the main function

```
#include<iostream>
#include"test_class.hpp"
#include<random>

int main(){
    test_class obj_test(69);

    int count = 10;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        std::cout << obj_test.get_num() << " at count " << count << std::endl;
        auto new_change = obj_test.get_num() - count;
        obj_test.set_num(new_change);
        count--;
    }
    
}
```

Aim: As count goes from 10 to 1 in the while loop, the num variable value should also decrease.

Observation: The value of num variable remains constant (initial value of 69) throughout the iteration. I played with lvalues and rvalues but I can't make it work as intended.

Comment: `void test_class::set_num(int& num){num = num;}` is wrong.

Comment: The problem is here `void test_class::set_num(int& num){num = num;}`. The `num` parameter hides class's `num` member. So, you are assigning `num` to itself rather than `test_class::num`. Either change the name of the `num` param, or change your code to `this->num = num;`.

Comment: Ahh yes, right. What was I thinking... thanks a lot!

Comment: I would also not pass an int by reference for the setter

Comment: You don't need a separate setter if your getter returns a non-`const` reference. You could write a setter that performs some additional validation on the input parameter, but then you'd also want to change your getter because once you have a reference to `test_class::val` you can just assign whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
void test_class::set_num(int& num){num = num;}
```

What exactly is happening here? You assign `num` to itself. This code does nothing. What you really want is

```cpp
void test_class::set_num(int& num){ this->num = num; }
```

Btw you would avoid this kind of errors if you declared

```cpp
void test_class::set_num(const int& num)
```

(or even without `&`) which you should do, since you don't modify `num` inside `set_num` function.

Comment: Your compiler should also warn you if you put enough warnings on. It's really good to turn warnings on and read them. My company's coding standards make variable name shadowing illegal, so in my setters, the argument is usually called value. `num = value;`.

Comment: I'd recommend both your recommendation for `const` as well as additionally not calling your input argument the same thing as your member variable. Just because the compiler can follow doesn't mean it's unambiguous to developers.